# How to read a paragraph from file as a single string in c++

Tags: c++, string, file

I m writing a c++ program that should read a file. If that file contains a set of sentences, say a paragraph, how would i make it to read the entire paragraph as a single string?
when i tried coding this, my program could read only the first word, and it stops when it sees the **space** sequence.

**For example:**

If my sentence is : `you are a great programmer.`

It should display : `you are a great programmer.`

But what i get is : `you`

how to code this...can anyone help me with an example?

Here is what i have tried so far :

```
string b;
    ifstream inFile( "file.txt", ios::in );
    if ( !inFile ) { cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl; exit( 1 ); } 
    inFile>>b;
```

Comment: post here, so far what you have done.

Comment: `char line[100]; ifstream read("filename"); read.getline (line,100);`

Comment: char b[];
ifstream inFile( "file.txt", ios::in );
if ( !inFile ) {
cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
exit( 1 );
}inFile>>b;

Comment: How do you define `paragraph`? A single line?

Comment: Have you noticed that your code does not compile? You should specify the size of an array, or initialize its content with an initializer list.

Comment: You probably need a loop of some type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input streams treat spaces as a string split delimiter by default. Try with [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) which reads until a new line character.

To read an entire paragraph, you could assume that an empty line specifies the end of a paragraph. So read until you reach an empty line:

```
std::string read_paragraph( std::istream& is )
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string line;

    do
    {
        std::getline( is , line );
        ss << line;
    } while( line != "" )

    return ss.str();
}
```

The code above reads the stream line by line, storing the current line at `line` and flushing it into a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) which stores the paragraph. We read the input until the current line is an empty line.

Comment: i need to read that entire paragraph and store it to a variable as a single string... how to do that..pls help...

Comment: Anyone knows whats wrong with the markdown URL syntax `[]()`?

Comment: @Manu343726 lo siento, no hablo español.

Comment: @stellarossa uups, sorry, the fu****ng browser have oppened the spanish version by default :)

Comment: Thank you Konrad, I haven't seen the space between.

Comment: How does this span multiple lines, as a paragraph can span multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::getline` with a delimiter as the EOF character:

```
using std::istream::traits_type;

std::string paragraph;
char eof = traits_type::to_char_type(traits_type::eof());

if (std::getline(file, paragraph, eof))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Some file systems may not have an EOF character.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a paragraph is a single line (terminated by a newline).

```
std::ifstream   file("MyData");


std::string  paragraph;
std::getline(file, paragraph);

// Print the line
std::cout << paragraph;
```

Reading in all the paragraphs:

```
std::ifstream   file("MyData");


std::string  paragraph;
while(std::getline(file, paragraph))
{    
    // Print the line
    std::cout << paragraph;
}
```